# Replicating canvas bug in iOS without hardware

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, testing, safari

I'm hitting a problem with some javascript that only happens on iOS devices.

Annoyingly I can't replicate the problem because I don't own an iOS device. Users are unable to upload photos to this test website (iPhone5s iOS8): http://ios.oddprints.appspot.com the safari browser just hangs

I've tried to replicate the bug using the iOS simulator on my macbook (configured to iPhone 5s, iOS8) but there is no problem in that setup.

Are there any alternative iOS emulators / VMs / real hardware farms etc that I could use?

Comment: There are not alternative simulator or emulators for iOS. Even the official iOS Simulator is just that a simulator not an emulator. So it actually use OSX to work and render controls, it comes close to the real thing but not close enough.

Comment: This is a known bug in iOS8. Hopefully a new version will fix it.

Comment: @eli, yeah, I realised that eventually. It was actually fixed yesterday by apple with the release of iOS 8.0.2

Comment: The Safari on the iOS simulator doesn't even have the same user agent string as real hardware. Sigh.